# Mocking an api request with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to write a Jest Test, that when I change a select, I get different data

I am getting data from reddit with this code

```js
const Reddit = {
  async getUrl(url) {
    const response = await fetch(`${url}.json?raw_json=1`);
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    console.log(jsonResponse);
    return jsonResponse;
  },
  async getPosts(url) {
    const response = await this.getUrl(url);
    return response.data.children;
  },
};

export default Reddit;
```

This works

My app runs like this

```js
function App({ categories = ["all"] }) {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("popular");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Reddit.getPosts("https://www.reddit.com/r/popular/")
      .then((response) => setPosts(response))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const delayDebounceFn = setTimeout(() => {
      Reddit.getPosts(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${searchTerm}/`)
        .then((response) => {
          setPosts(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          Reddit.getPosts("https://www.reddit.com/r/popular/").then(
            (response) => setPosts(response)
          );
        });
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(delayDebounceFn);
  }, [searchTerm]);

  const postHintsToIgnore = ["link", "hosted:video", "rich:video"];
  categories = ["all", "self", "image"];
  const filteredPosts = posts.filter(
    (post) =>
      !postHintsToIgnore.includes(post.data.post_hint) &&
      post.data.hasOwnProperty("post_hint") === true
  );

  const displayedPosts =
    filteredPosts.length > 0 ? (
      filteredPosts.map((post) => <Card data={post.data} key={post.data.id} />)
    ) : (
      <div className="noPosts">
        <h2>No posts showing on?</h2>
        <p>This could be for a variety of reasons</p>
        <ul>
          <li>We are only showing images and text posts for now</li>
          <li>This subreddit does not use the 'post_hint' metadata</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header onChange={handleChange} />
      <ContentFilter categories={categories} />
      {displayedPosts}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This also works

However I am write a test

```js
  it("should only show posts with Self on change", async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    render(<App categories={categories} />);
    await user.selectOptions(screen.getByRole("combobox"), "SELF");

    expect(screen.getByRole("combobox")).toHaveValue("self");
    expect(screen.getByRole("option", { name: "SELF" }).selected).toBe(true);
    await waitFor(() => {
      const contentContainerComponent = screen.findByRole("main", {
        name: "ContentContainer",
      });

      expect(contentContainerComponent).toBeInTheDocument();
      const textElement = screen.getByText(
        "[https://twitter.com/SwissIceHockey/status/1731601782554370344](https://twitter.com/SwissIceHockey/status/1731601782554370344)"
      );
      expect(textElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
```

And always getting this to show up (ie, no reddit data showing)

```html
              <h2>
                No posts showing on?
              </h2>
              <p>
                This could be for a variety of reasons
              </p>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  We are only showing images and text posts for now
                </li>
                <li>
                  This subreddit does not use the 'post_hint' metadata
                </li>
```

I have tried mocking my Reddit code, but it doesn't seem to display any data

```js
const Reddit = {
  getUrl: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(data)),
  getPosts: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(posts)),
};

jest.spyOn(Reddit, "getPosts").mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(posts));
jest.spyOn(Reddit, "getUrl").mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(data));
```

How would I mock this correctly?